# addEventListener method does not work on items coming from an HTML collection

Tags: reactjs, typescript, function, react-hooks

I'm using React and TypeScript and as I mentioned in the title, the addEventListener method does not work when the target item comes from an HTML collection as shown below

[image]

But it does work when I target an specific element like:

[image]

I'm calling the function after the targets are rendered by using useEffect
like this:

[image]

and also tried without the hook, the function is not triggered so there's nothing to show in the console.

I also tried through a handler added to an onClick event when I create the element:
[image]

The linkHandler handles all functions calls by calling them like this:
[image]

and that works just fine but I'd love to know whats going on when I try to use the addEventListener method in an element coming from a collection.

I hope I was clear enough, thanks in advance!

Comment: Please do not add your source code listings as images. Add them directly in the question, see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Answer (score 1):

If you are using react you should not use `addEventListener` neither `getElementsByClassName`. To access a element on the screen the best way is to use `useRef` and `forwardRef`

with a ref of an element you can easily do `<ref>.current.click()` to simulate a click event

Here are some documentation that can help you:
[about useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref), [about forwardRef](https://www.carlrippon.com/react-forwardref-typescript/)